# Relentless attempt to access page control from a static method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, static-methods, webmethod

As stated in the heading i have been making relentless efforts to access page controls inside a static method.

What i did is as below in the image but still i see the controls as null ? I have an idea that the viewstate is not passed to the static method, is that the case?

The method test is called via jQuery ajax.

[image: The code and the expanded page object]

Answer (score 0):

No problem with calling static method, Have you checked if the current handler is not already null on the 'test' method? It might be that you access the current handler but is not constructed yet in the ASP.Net pipeline? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#general_page_lifecycle_stages for page life cycle.

Comment: i too suspect that, but if that's the case how can one ensure that its done because on making a ajax request the page load method doesn't get called but only the WebMethod

Comment: You are right, using an Ajax call the page wont exist because it does not make use of the ViewState.

Comment: You will have to relook at your approach what you want to achieve.